# How to move multiple turtles in a for loop?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So, I am a recent beginner to python and for my class I am being tasked with making a turtle race with 10 turtles that all move and should stop at the finish line. I was given directions to make a list for the turtles and have a while loop to make them move a random amount and a nested if loop to check for the winner. I am having trouble making all the turtles move at once, when I run my code, it moves the turtles one by one instead of all together, any ideas?

````
import turtle as trtl
import random as rand
zoomers = []
zom = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
tloc = -130
trtl.penup()
trtl.goto(-150, 150)
trtl.pendown()
trtl.goto(-150,-140)
trtl.penup()
trtl.goto(180,150)
trtl.pendown()
trtl.goto(180,-140)
trtl.hideturtle()
for z in zom:
  zoom = trtl.Turtle("turtle")
  zoom.penup()
  zoom.goto(-150,-tloc)
  tloc += 25
  robux = rand.randrange(0,20)
  zoomers.append(zoom)
  for n in zoomers:
    cash = 0
    while cash < 100:
      zoom.forward(robux)
      cash = cash + 1
    if zoom.xcor() == 180:
      print("We have a winner!")
      break```
````

Comment: Are you assuming that they are moving in parallel e.g. if two turtles reach the finish line in the same while loop iteration they are **both** winners? or will it go in order e.g whichever turtle is first found across the threshold wins

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
"This doesn't do what I want" is not enough, in this case.

Comment: It's not clear just how you expect this to work.  It seems that you wrote about 30 lines of code before testing it.  Please properly describe your approach: your triple-nested loops (for-for-while) seem to work against the result you want.  Your `while` loop is simply a 100-iteration loop; what are you doing, and why didn't you use a `for`?
I'm afraid that "fixing" your described problem would involve writing the main body of your program for you, which is out of scope here.

Comment: I must use a while statement to make them move forward a random amount, and the while loop being 100 is something I put that will likely be changed to something lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a single turtle. You can easily do this by creating multiple turtle objects. I have used 3 turtle objects and they have a small race.

Try this code and you can implement your winner logic in this code.

```
import turtle as trtl
import random as rand

zoom1 = trtl.Turtle()
zoom2 = trtl.Turtle()
zoom3 = trtl.Turtle()

zoomers = [zoom1, zoom2, zoom3]

for zoom in zoomers:
  zoom.penup()

zoom1.goto(-150, 150)
zoom2.goto(-120, 150)
zoom3.goto(-90, 150)

for zoom in zoomers:
  zoom.pendown()
  zoom.right(90)

for zoom in zoomers:
  robux = rand.randrange(10,50)
  zoom.forward(robux)
```

**Edit**: You need non-blocking code to implement turtles moving simultaneously and independently of each other. You can do that by using multi-threading. Try [this](http://www.tigerjython.com/engl/index.php?inhalt_links=navigation.inc.php&inhalt_mitte=anhang/parallelverarbeitung.inc.php).

Comment: @AnnZen  I think to move turtles simultaneously, implement multi-threading and start those turtles? Because running them all in a loop is blocking the next turtle. Can you suggest something simpler?

Comment: Yes, but updating screen on each iteration is accurate-ish. Problem is still the same turtles are moving one by one, their movement is not independent of each other.

[Found this by the way](http://www.tigerjython.com/engl/index.php?inhalt_links=navigation.inc.php&inhalt_mitte=anhang/parallelverarbeitung.inc.php)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a direct way to do that, but here is the next best thing.

Create a turtle `Screen`. Set its [`tracer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.tracer) to `0`, and update the screen in each iteration of the loop. It can get too fast, so import `sleep` from the `time` module to slow things down a little.

Minimal example:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randrange
from time import sleep

wn = Screen()
wn.tracer(0)

t1 = Turtle('turtle')
t2 = Turtle('turtle')

t1.penup()
t2.penup()

t1.goto(-100, 50)
t2.goto(-100, -50)

while True:
    sleep(0.1)
    t1.forward(randrange(0, 20))
    t2.forward(randrange(0, 20))
    wn.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

All the other solutions so far move the turtles a random distance in a fixed time slice.  Let's turn that around and move the turtles a constant distance in a random time slice:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randrange

def run(turtle):
    turtle.forward(5)

    if turtle.xcor() < half_width:
        screen.ontimer(lambda: run(turtle), randrange(20, 150))

screen = Screen()

half_width = screen.window_width() / 2
lane_width = 20

for order, color in enumerate(['red', 'green', 'blue']):
    turtle = Turtle('turtle')
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.penup()

    turtle.goto(-half_width, (order | 1) * lane_width)
    lane_width *= -1
    run(turtle)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 1):

We can model this without even using the `turtle` library:

```
import random

twerbles = list(zip(range(10), [0]*10)) #list of turtles all starting at position 0 (numbered 0-10)
finishline = 10 #the threshold they must pass

while True:
    twerbles = [(twerble, position+random.randint(1,2)) for twerble, position in twerbles] #move each turtle up a random amount.

    print(twerbles) #this can be removed if you dont want to see their positions as they go

    winners = [twerble for twerble, position in twerbles if position >= finishline] #list of turtles that passed the threshold (if any)
    if winners: print(winners); break #if there are winners print them and stop looping
```

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (5, 2), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 2)]
[(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 4), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 3), (9, 3)]
[(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4), (5, 6), (6, 5), (7, 5), (8, 4), (9, 5)]
[(0, 5), (1, 7), (2, 6), (3, 5), (4, 6), (5, 8), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 5), (9, 6)]
[(0, 6), (1, 8), (2, 8), (3, 6), (4, 7), (5, 9), (6, 7), (7, 9), (8, 7), (9, 7)]
[(0, 8), (1, 9), (2, 10), (3, 7), (4, 9), (5, 11), (6, 8), (7, 11), (8, 8), (9, 9)]

[2, 5, 7] #winning turtles
```

moving w/ turtles

```
import turtle as trtl
import random

finishline = 30

twerbles = [(trtl.Turtle("turtle"), 0) for i in range(10)]

for i,(twerble,position) in enumerate(twerbles):
  twerble.penup()
  twerble.goto(-150,150 - i*25)

while True:
    twerbles = [(twerble, position+random.randint(1,2)) for twerble, position in twerbles]

    for twerble, position in twerbles:
        twerble.forward(position)

    winners = [twerble for twerble, position in twerbles if position >= finishline]
    if winners:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a collection of turtles. Loop movement (a single step) for each turtle until a turtle finishes.

Try this code:

```
import turtle as trtl
import random as rand
zoomers = []
zom = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
tloc = -130
trtl.penup()
trtl.goto(-150, 150)
trtl.pendown()
trtl.goto(-150,-140)
trtl.penup()
trtl.goto(180,150)
trtl.pendown()
trtl.goto(180,-140)
trtl.hideturtle()

zoomers = [trtl.Turtle("turtle") for z in zom]

for i,t in enumerate(zoomers):
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-150,150 - i*25)


for i,z in enumerate(zom):
  zoom = zoomers[i]   #trtl.Turtle("turtle")
  tloc += 25
#  zoomers.append(zoom)

running = True
while running:
    for zoom in zoomers:
      robux = rand.randrange(0,20)
      zoom.forward(robux)
      if zoom.xcor() >= 180:
        print("We have a winner!")
        running = False
        break

input('Press enter to exit...')
```